# How do I find the equation of the surface that is obtained by rotating the ellipse $\alpha(u) = (c + a\cos u, b\sin u, 0)$ around the y axis

Tags: differential-geometry

How do I find the equation of the surface that is obtained by rotating the ellipse $\alpha(u) = (c + a\cos u, b\sin u, 0)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}+$ and $c > 0$. Find the Gaussian and mean curvature (elliptical torus)

I honestly don't know how to work with rotational surface, but I think I would understand it if I saw how it's done. We were left to do these assignments and we haven't done any like this. Just a theoretical base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface is a surface of revolution; it's some kind of torus. For this torus $r=(x,y,z)$. The distance of every point in the torus to the $y$ axis is $\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$ and for points in the torus with $y$ constant, this distance is too constant. Consider points with $y=b\sin u$, then this distance is the same as the $x_e$ coordinate for the corresponding $y_e$ coordinate in the ellipse ($x_e=c+a\cos u$), so $x^2+z^2=(c+a\cos u)^2$. Now,

$x=m\cos\theta$ and $z=m\sin\theta$

$m^2\cos^2\theta+m^2\sin^2\theta=(c+a\cos u)^2\implies m=\pm(c+a\cos u)$ We choose the positive one. Then,

$r=((c+a\cos u)\cos\theta, b\sin u,(c+a\cos u)\sin\theta)$

Comment: isn't the distance to the $y$ axis $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$

Comment: This doesn't change anything in the final answer, just saying for precision's sake.

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I was thinking of that quantity as constant because the distance is constant.

Comment: The answer has **two** errors compensating one to another. I am very sorry. I fix them now. (I checked the solution by plotting it and it was ok).